# Can I use a generic type argument as a return type?

Tags: c#, generics, return-type

If I have an interface with one or more generic arguments...

```
interface IFoo<T1, T2> {}
```

...is it possible to refer to one or more of it's generic argument types in the return type of a method which takes it as an argument?

```
static IFoo.T2 Grab(IFoo<T1, T2> foo)
{
    // TODO: return something.
}
```

Comment: `static T2 Grab(IFoo<T1, T2> foo)`?

Comment: In order for that *parameter* declaration to be valid, `Grab` must already be inside a class with (at least) `T1` and `T2` as declared type parameters. So just use `T2`.

Comment: Either the method or its enclosing class must be generic as well.  Like `static T Grab<T, U>(IFoo<T, U> foo)` as an example of making the method generic.  Or just nail the type parameters down, like `static int Grab(IFoo<int, string> foo)`.  Or make it generic with one type parameter, `static T Grab<T>(IFoo<T, string> foo)`, closest to the question perhaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on how you defined `T1` and `T2` within your class. You have two opportunities:

1. make your class containing the static method generic:

   ```
   class MyClass<T1, T2>
   {
       static T2 Grab(IFoo<T1, T2> foo) { ... }
   }
   ```
2. make only the method itself generic:

   ```
   static T2 Grab<T1, T2>(IFoo<T1, T2> foo) { ... }
   ```

In both cases you can´t simply use the generic argument from `IFoo`, because there literally *is* no instance of that interface. And even if you had such an instance, it has nothing to do with your method.